# Top-level Async Function Expression Calls in NodeJS don't work anymore?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a NodeJS module that I use as a server that has this async function expression call at the top level:

```js
...
(async function func() {
    await sleep(180000);
    // do some stuff
})();
...
globalThis.sleep = function sleep(time) {
    return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, time));
};
...
```

When I was running this in NodeJS version 19.9.0, it didn't have any problems. However, I just updated today to version 20.2.0 and now it gives me this:

```
TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (exec.js:59:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1255:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1309:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1113:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

Oddly enough, when I put a `console.log("dummy message");` right before the function call, it calls the function immediately, no Promise microtask (and throws a `ReferenceError` for the `sleep()` function). I tried wrapping the function in `console.log()` instead of calling it, and sure enough, it says `[AsyncFunction func]`. I tried downgrading back to version 19.9.0, but it still has the same problem. What went wrong, and how do I fix it?

OS: Linux 6.3.2-arch1-1
Using Arch Linux's Pacman

Comment: I get a totally different error because you're trying to use `sleep()` before it is defined... _"ReferenceError: sleep is not defined"_. Removing the assignment to `globalThis.sleep` hoists the function and it works as expected. It's not clear at all why you get the error in your question.

Comment: @Phil Function `sleep()` is assigned to the `globalThis` object because my code loads modules that need to access the same function (among others). I call `sleep()` before it's declared on the assumption that none of an async function is executed on the tick it is called, which I was assured was true until today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What this code *should* be doing in all versions of Node is throwing a ReferenceError as you described, because you're trying to use `globalThis.sleep` before you've assigned it.

My guess is that you left off a semicolon on the line before the async function, so the parentheses around it are getting interpreted as a function call with the async function as the parameter. This would explain why adding a semicolon-terminated line of code before it gets the correct (ReferenceError-throwing) behavior. You'll need to fix both that and the ReferenceError to get this code working.

Comment: You're right about the semicolon, and the the first part executing synchronously (had to check MDN docs). The question is now, why was it working before?